# Extruding buildings without them floating in qgis2threejs

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I am trying to extrude building footprints relative to the DEM. But buildings seem to be floating in the air.
[image]
[image]
height_2 represents the heights of the buildings.

Comment: How is it that the `elevation_clipped` layer had red lines running on it? From the screenshot it is not clear if those are contours or if they represent roads. If they are roads, the `elevation_clipped` is not a real DEM layer. Make sure you have a real DEM raster (i.e. only elevation information) to be used as an altitude reference.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Elevation_Clipped` as the Z-coordinate reference, there is no need to add an `Altitude` expression.

In your settings:

[image]

the buildings start being extruded from a Z coordinate which is the sum of two values:

```
Z coordinate = z from Elevation_Clipped + height_2
```

This can be clearly seen as the tallest buildings are the ones which "float" higher.

Try using a setting like the following instead:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you only have to point to your "Elevation Clipper" layer to get the correct z-values. By adding the Expression "height_2" under "Altitude" your are moving every building by its own height.
So "height_2" should only be used at a "Style".